# How do we calculate the power of a PMSM Motor and inverter

Tags: pmsm

I have a motor controller running FOC control to control a PMSM motor.
I was wondering how do we calculate the power consumed by the motor (just the motor).
I have a DC-DC converter which outputs 300 V to the inverter's DC bus. And at a constant load on the motor, the DC-DC converter shows that it is consuming about 6 A.
So the input power to the complete system would be 1.8 kW.

Measuring at the motor terminals, I see that each phase is consuming about 30 A RMS.
Plugging in the motor power equation:

P = sqrt(3) * V * I * power factor

sqrt(3) * 300 * 30 * 0.9 = 14 kW

How can this be possible input power is greater than the output power? Could someone please clarify!

EDIT:
Nominal DC bus is reduced to 270 V.
Test Constants: Speed of the motor is 1000 RPM, and it is has got 1 Nm torque as load.

Calculating DC side power is simple V * I:

270*1.566 = 422 W

Calculating AC side power:

Power = sqrt(3) * VL-L * I * power factor

So sqrt(3) * 50.23 * 9.539 * 1.0 = 829 W

How can AC power be greater than DC power? or the formula that i have used is wrong?

Attaching waveform.
C1: DC bus (Positive probe of DC+ and negative probe on DC-)

C2: DC current (Current probe on DC+ line)

C3: Line to Line voltage (Positive probe on Phase U terminal, negative probe on Phase V terminal.

C4: Phase U current (Current probe on Phase U line going to the motor)

[image: Waveforms at 1 Nm torque]

Comment: Please measure the motor voltage. It's probably less than 300 V. You will also have a cos phi between voltage and current.

Comment: The motor voltage(line to line) is actually a square wave of varying duty cycle(space vector), of amplitude 0 to 300v, So while calculating power what can i stake the voltage to be in this case?

Comment: With square wave drive, if your current triangular?

Comment: No, the current is a since wave

Comment: Please show oscillogram.

Comment: @winny are you available?, I will post the waveforms , I complexly forgot about this.

Comment: I have added the waveform, please have a look!, I have assumed power factor as 1 as the voltage and current are almost in phase

Comment: Can you set your scope to calculate the RMS voltage? It looks very high frequency so you may need to zoom in further.

Comment: It does calculate RMS voltage, (At the Top), Do you want it more zoomed?, i have taken 6 cycles data.

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Does it stay the same if you zoom in to cover just one cycle, or zoom out to cover more? Scopes work differently when there is "folding" of the waveshape.

Comment: Its stays the same even if I zoom in to one cycle also, similar result when i zoom out as well. One more point I forgot to mention, all channels are bandwidth limited to 500 KHz, If i remove the BW limit, the nice sine shape of C3 disappears and you get  a square shaped signal. If AC power is calculated with that , its even worse :(

Comment: This is the issue, "slow" AC waveshape but very fast switching = needs both fast sampling and long memory to capture the entire thing. But assume 50.22 V is correct and calculate the power.

Comment: I did use 55.22, but the AC side power is double that of the DC side power, how can this be? Is there any other approach that I can take to calculate power?

Comment: sqrt(3) missing + driver losses?

Comment: Could you please elaborate, I don't get what "sqrt(3) missing + driver losses" mean?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152248/discussion-between-winny-and-ak47).